# Esperar resultado de promesas en node. Promesas recursivas

Tags: nodejs, express, promesas

Tengo unas APIs desarrolladas en node con expres. Tengo un metodo que devuelve un arreglo de objetos (Empleados), deseo que ese método sea recursivo ya que un empleado puede ser jefe de otro empleado y ese mismo empleado puede ser jefe de otro empleado por lo tanto deseo obtener todos los empleados que estén por debajo de un empleado.
Mi problema es que no le da tiempo de consultar todos los empleados y devuelve la respuesta incompleta

Tengo entendido que se debe usar Promise.all pero no se como implementarlo

```
finEmpledoACargoByProyecto = async (searchElemento: ISearchEmpleados): Promise<IEmpleados[]> => {
    try {
        const request = (await mssqlpool.connect()).request();

        const sql = `Select e.* , u.username,
        CONCAT(p.nombre, ' ', p.paterno, ' ', p.materno)as nombre from empleadoProyectos as emp, empleados as e
        left join autenticacion.dbo.usuarios as u on u.idUsuario = e.idEmpleado
        left join autenticacion.dbo.personas as p on p.idPersona = u.idPersona
        where e.idEmpleado in (select e.idEmpleado from empleados as e group by e.idEmpleado)
        and e.idEmpleadoJefe in (select e.idEmpleadoJefe from empleados as e group by e.idEmpleadoJefe)
        and e.idEmpleado = emp.idEmpleado
        and (e.idEmpleadoJefe = ${searchElemento.idEmpleadoJefe} or e.idEmpleado = ${searchElemento.idEmpleadoJefe})
        ${searchElemento.idProyecto!=0? `and emp.idProyecto = ${searchElemento.idProyecto}` : ''}
        `;

       //Este arreglo debe hacer la recursión 
        this.empleados = (await request.query(sql)).recordset

        return this.empleados;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error en el metodo finEmpledoACargoByProyecto", error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quieres hacer recursividad con promesas?

Comment: Si asi es, eso es lo que quiero hacer

Comment: La recursividad no tiene nada que ver con tu problema, ya que si vuelves a ejecutar la función te seguirá trayendo la misma información una y otra vez. Esa consulta sql te trae la info correcta si la ejecutas en tu motor de base de datos? que libreria estas usando como orm? @ObethMorales